# Why am I getting traceback and value errors when trying to run NLTK import?

Tags: python, import, nltk

I have downloaded NLTK-3.5 and successfully ran the pip install nltk command.  When running 'import nltk' in Python 3.8, I am getting the following error:

> > > 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk_*init*_.py", line 128, in 
from nltk.collocations import *
File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 39, in 
from nltk.metrics import (
File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics_*init*_.py", line 16, in 
from nltk.metrics.scores import (
File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics\scores.py", line 15, in 
from scipy.stats.stats import betai
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, open the files listed and deleting spaces (that generates indentation errors) and just don't know what to do next.

Any suggestions for solving this problem?

Thank you!
Genie

Comment: please provide more environment information.  Win or Mac?
There is a comment to avoid 64 versions???  https://www.nltk.org/install.html

Comment: Of course, sorry. I am running windows 10, 64 bit. Thank you for the link.

Comment: I downloaded nltk 3.5 (latest version) and installing (or trying to) on Python 3.8.2